# Dynamics 365 API RetrieveMultipleRequest to return raw XML response?

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are using an Azure Function with the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk to query Dynamics 365 instances with Fetch XML.

The FetchXML Builder provides a function to return raw XML:

[image]

I took a look at this project on Github and found out that it is possible to get the XML with

```
var response = (ExecuteFetchResponse)ServiceClient.Execute(new ExecuteFetchRequest() { FetchXml = xml });
```

However, this is **deprecated**. (Although Microsoft is not using Obsolete-Annotations...)

The documentation says that Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveMultipleRequest should be used instead.

**Is it possible to get the response xml somehow this way?**

Comment: do you really need xml response? I think any xml serializer can produce a pretty good xml from the EntityCollection Entities property you get when using RetrieveMultiple

Comment: Yes, customer wants it.

Comment: The FetchXML queried before can be pretty much anything FetchXML offers. Serializing the EntityCollection is no fun, I already tried it. So to create the same response as my deprecated code above I would iterate over all objects and then over all attributes which could be anything the CRM offers again. I don't really want to spend that effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to approach it is to observe what HTTP requests and responses are made from your Azure Function. Either by attaching to SDK using reflection, or [diagnostics](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/capturing-and-tracing-all-http-requests-in-c-and-net/).

Other option is not to use SDK, but [FetchXML via Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/use-fetchxml-web-api). Response will be json, not xml. But it's still a raw response convertible to xml.